# Unchecking mirror displays logs user out on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have anApple MBP Retina 15inch, Late 2013, Nvidia GeForce GT 750 2048MB, OS X 10.9.5

If I connect one monitor, I can mirror or extend the desktop without a problem.
If I connect two monitors, it immediately mirrors all three (MBP display & both externals).

If I go in to System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement and uncheck "Mirror Displays", **it immediately logs me out** and shows the login prompt on all three screens.

I've tried a variety of things from restarts, to NVRAM flush, to windowserver.plist deletion, to Color Sync utility setting to Factory..  none effect this issue in the least.

I'm not sure where next to look.  What system would I look at to see this event (unchecking of mirror displays) failing?  Short of clean installing OS X (not really an option), how do I convince OS X to forget everything it's been told about displays and reset itself?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Gotta love users..  a bit of latent info.  Before this stopped working, he was trying to get remote desktop working and issued the following command for that:

`sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw mypasswd -restart -agent -privs -all`

How do I unscrew that whatever it did?

Comment: Gotta love users..  a bit of latent info.  Before this stopped working, he was trying to get remote desktop working and issued the following command for that:

`sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw mypasswd -restart -agent -privs -all`

How do I unscrew that whatever it did?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the ARD kickstart file itself right now, and it looks like someone copy-pasted from it verbatim (not knowing what those options did?) or was told to run those bits.

I'd start with shutting ARD down, so you can figure out the kickstart file(per the kickstart file, "Stop the Remote Management service and deactivate it so it will not start after the next computer restart."):

> sudo
>   /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart
>   -deactivate -stop

That should stop and disable the Remote Management client(note that it survives reboot, so you'll have to figure out the right options and turn it back on if you do remote-manage them).

Below is a (long) copy/paste from the options listed in the kickstart file, but first, some interpretation based on the kickstart file:

> kickstart -activate    -configure -access -on 
>             -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes 
>             -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw mypasswd 
>             -restart -agent -privs -all

Partial matches here:

> Activate the Remote Management service, enable access, and restart the agent.
>
> kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -restart -agent

and here:

> Give admin and bob all access.
>
> kickstart -configure -access -on -privs -all -users admin,bob

and here:

> Allow access for all users and give all users full access.
>
> kickstart -configure -allowAccessFor -allUsers -privs -all

If that was me, I'd be shutting that down in a hurry. It looks to me like that config sets that client to accept a pretty bad VNC password from anyone and gives them full access. It also currently does this automatically on boot.

> Examples:
>
> - Uninstall program files (but not preferences and settings), install the given package, and then restart the service.
>     kickstart
>     -uninstall -files -install -package RD_Admin_Install.pkg -restart -console
> - Install the given package and then restart the ARD agent.
>     kickstart -install -package RD_Client_Install.pkg -restart -agent
> - On 10.4 and earlier, stop the Remote Management service but, if activated, it will start after the next computer restart. On 10.5 and later, use kickstart -deactivate instead.
>     kickstart -stop
> - Stop the Remote Management service and deactivate it so it will not start after the next computer restart.
>     kickstart -deactivate -stop
> - Restart the agent.
>     kickstart -restart -agent -console
> - Activate the Remote Management service and then restart the agent.   kickstart -activate -restart -agent -console
> - Activate the Remote Management service, enable access, and restart the agent.
>     kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -restart
>     -agent
> - Disable user access.
>     kickstart -configure -access -off
> - Give admin and bob all access.
>     kickstart -configure -access -on -privs -all -users admin,bob
> - Use Directory Server accounts for authentication. Users must be a member of one of the ARD directory groups to authenticate.
>     kickstart
>     -configure -clientopts -setdirlogins -dirlogins yes
> - Disable the Remote Management menu extra.
>     kickstart -configure -clientopts -setmenuextra -menuextra no
>
> The following examples are only for OS X 10.5 and later.
>
> - Allow access for only these users (the users must be specified in a separate command).
>     kickstart -configure -allowAccessFor
>     -specifiedUsers
> - Allow access for all users and give all users full access.
>     kickstart -configure -allowAccessFor -allUsers -privs -all
> - Start the Remote Management service.
>     kickstart -activate
>
> RUNNING FROM THE COMMAND LINE
>
> This script can be run like any UNIX tool from the command line or
>   called from another script.
>
> Before starting:
>
> - Use this script at your own risk.  Read it first and understand it.
> - Log in as an administrator (you must have sudo privileges)
> - Copy this script to any location you like (such as /usr/bin/local/)
> - Ensure this file has Unix line endings, or it won't run.
>
> Running:
>
> - Run the script using "sudo" (enter your password if prompted)
>
>   sudo ./kickstart -restart -agent
>
> Command-line switches:
>
> The optional "parent" switches activate the top level kickstart
>   features:
>
> -uninstall
>   -install
>   -deactivate 
>   -activate 
>   -configure 
>   -stop
>   -restart
>
> These features can be selected independently, but will always be done
>   in the order shown above.
>
> For anything interesting to happen, you *must* specify one or more of
>   the parent options, plus one or more child options for those that
>   require them.  Child options will be ignored unless their parent
>   option is also supplied.
>
> All options are switches (they take no arguments), except for -package
>    -users  and -mask , as noted below.
>
> -uninstall  ## Enable the "uninstall" options:
>
> ```
>          -files    ## Uninstall all ARD-related files   
>          -settings ## Remove access privileges in System Preferences   
>          -prefs    ## Remove Remote Desktop administrator preferences
> ```
>
> -install    ## Enable the "install" options:
>
> -package path ## Specify the path to an installer package to run
>
> -configure  ## Enable the "configure" options:
>
> -users john,admin ## Specify users to set privs or access (default
>   is all users)
>
> -activate ## Activate ARD agent in Sys Prefs to run at startup
>
> -deactivate ## Deactivate ARD agent in Sys Prefs to run at startup
>
> -access   ## Set access for users: 
>          -on     ## Grant access
>          -off    ## Deny  access
>
> -privs    ## Set the user's access privileges:
>
> ```
>    -none               ## Disable all privileges for specified user
>    -all                ## Grant all privileges (default)...
>                        ## ... or grant any these privileges...
>    -DeleteFiles        ##
>    -ControlObserve     ## Control AND observe (unless ObserveOnly is also specified)
>    -TextMessages       ## Send a text message
>    -ShowObserve        ## Show client when being observed or controlled
>    -OpenQuitApps       ## Open and quit aplicationns
>    -GenerateReports    ## Generate reports (and search hard drive)
>    -RestartShutDown    ##
>    -SendFiles          ## Send *and/or* retrieve files
>    -ChangeSettings     ## Change system settings
>    -ObserveOnly        ## Modify ControlObserve option to allow Observe mode only
>    -mask number        ## Specify "naprivs" mask numerically instead (advanced)
> ```
>
> -allowAccessFor ## Specify the Remote Management access mode
>
> ```
>    -allUsers       ## Grant access to all local users
>    -specifiedUsers ## Only grant access to users with privileges
> ```
>
> -computerinfo         ## Specify all four computer info fields
>   (default for each is empty)
>
> ```
>     -set1 -1 <text> 
>     -set2 -2 <text> 
>     -set3 -3 <text> 
>     -set4 -4 <text>
> ```
>
> -clientopts           ## Allow specification of several opts.
>
> ```
>     -setmenuextra -menuextra  yes|no        ## Set whether menu extra appears in menu bar
>     -setdirlogins -dirlogins  yes|no        ## Set whether directory logins are allowed
>     -setreqperm   -reqperm    yes|no        ## Allow VNC guests to request permission
>     -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy  yes|no        ## Allow VNC Legacy password mode
>     -setvncpw     -vncpw      mynewpw       ## Set VNC Legacy PW
>     -setwbem      -wbem       yes|no        ## Allow incoming WBEM requests over IP
> ```
>
> -stop       ## Stop the agent and/or console program (N/A if targetdisk is not /)
>
> -restart    ## Enable the "restart" options:         (N/A if targetdisk is not /)
>
> -agent    ## Restart the ARD Agent and helper   -console  ## Restart
>   the console application   -menu     ## Restart the menu extra
>
> -targetdisk    ## Disk on which to operate, specified as a mountpoint in the current filesystem.  Defaults to the current boot volume: "/".
>   NOTE: Disables the -restart options (does not affect currently running processes).
>
> -verbose    ## Print (non-localizable) output from installer tool (if used)
>
> -quiet      ## No feedback; just run.
>
> -help       ## Print this extended help message